# PDFView not resizing

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

We have given static height and width to PDFView. Assume that 300 * 300

After that, we are loading **document** from Remote URL and adding into PDFView. The **direction** will be **vertical**.

It's not adapting to base size we had given, its horizontally scrolling and zooming also not good.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            // Instantiate PDFDocument
            let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: URL(string: "http://res.cloudinary.com/didzg9k3p/image/upload/v1564484497/Kuwy/2019/07/30/KW71211144636907/KW71211144636907/zvzinxp5oqwku2kqpwv6.pdf")!)
            self.pdfView.document = pdfDoc
            self.pdfView.autoScales = true
            self.pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
            self.pdfView.backgroundColor = .orange
            let scaleFactor = self.pdfView.scaleFactor
            self.pdfView.scaleFactor = scaleFactor
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: try moving code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear. you get the same issues?

Comment: still issue coming

Answer (score 0):

Can you add and try that code after autoScales assignment?
`pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit`